# How to get Access Token and Access token secret without call back URL Onedrive

Tags: twitter-oauth, access-token, onedrive

This is first time I use onedrive API. 
I want to create application that need using onedrive service.

When I want to create application Onedrive only give me `APP_CLIENT_ID` and `APP_CLIENT_SECRET`.

Then to get access token and access token secret we have to use call back URL. 
They will give me URL then I have to paste in the browser then press allow. 
[image]

after that I'll get URL return, and then now I have access.

My question is, is there any way that I can get access token and access token secret directly like on Twitter?.

When I want to create application on Twitter, I can generate access token and access token secret, so I dont need to paste the url then press allow and etc.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform is your application for?

Answer (score 0):

When you request the scopes for you application you can include "wl.offline_access", which will return a refresh token which you application can use to generate a new refresh token.

See more details in the authentication section from the OneDrive Development site: 
https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#step-3-get-a-new-access-token-or-refresh-token

Comment: Hi Peter, did you ever try to register application on Twitter?. When I register app to twitter I can directly generate access token and access secret token so I dont need to user call back URL that I have to put that url then clik ok then get the return code. I just want to skip that process by put access token and access secret token on my code.

Comment: Are you referring to the Application-only Authentication model that Twitter has?  If that is the case, OneDrive does not have support for such a authorization model at this time.Could you expand on your app's scenario?